# Invalid checksum while deploying to GKE using github-actions

Tags: docker, google-kubernetes-engine, github-actions

I want to deploy my code to GKE using github actions but I'm getting an error during the publish step:

```
The push refers to repository [europe-west1-c-docker.pkg.dev/***/samples/static-site]
83109fa660b2: Preparing
30d3c4334a23: Preparing
f2fa9f4cf8fd: Preparing
f2fa9f4cf8fd: Layer already exists
30d3c4334a23: Layer already exists
83109fa660b2: Layer already exists
invalid checksum digest format
```

[image]

I'm new to docker so I assume my dockerfile might be at fault:

```
# Pull base image.
FROM ubuntu:14.04

# Define default command.
CMD ["bash"]
```

Inside my google.yml there is an enviroment variable which I don't know the purpose of that I think also might be at fault:

```
REPOSITORY: samples # TODO: update to Artifact Registry docker repository
IMAGE: static-site
```

I haven't done any actions related to these two inside google cloud and haven't changed them from their defaults.

C++ code, Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$GAR_LOCATION` should be the region of the Artifact Registry, here you entered `europe-west1-c` which is a zone (the region would be `europe-west1`).

Put instead the region of your GAR (= Google Artifact Registry) if you already have it created, or create an Artifact Registry before (it's easy to do with the console).